# Using d3.select on a python-generated object

Tags: python, d3.js, plot, mpld3

I'm using mpld3 to create a graph in a web app. I want to allow the user to drag the orange line.

[image]

I explicitly want to code this drag-and-drop behavior directly in d3.js, because d3.js allows me to set restrictions on the drag behavior (specifically I want to allow only horizontal drag, as shows in [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0f6dycmx/).)

I am having trouble selecting the orange line element. I am getting its ID with `mpld3.utils.get_id()`, but passing this id on the JS side to either `d3.select()` or to `mpld3.get_element()` does not work.

```py
import mpld3
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(-1,1,20)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,x**3)
line = ax.plot([0,0],[-1,0])

js = '''
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
'''

html = mpld3.fig_to_html(fig)

print(mpld3.utils.get_id(line)) # gives something like 'el68722312816129664'

with open('pured3_output.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(html+js)
```

After opening `pured3_output.html` in the browser, I type this in the browser console:

```
>>> mpld3.get_element('el68722312816129664')
null
```

```
>>> d3.select('#el68722312816129664')
Selection {_groups: Array(1), _parents: Array(1)}
```

I don't know what it's returning but it's clearly not the right thing, because, `d3.select('#el68722312816129664').remove()` doesn't do anything.

I'm not particularly attached to using mpld3, compared to other packages built on top of d3.js, such as Plotly. I am using mpld3 so far because it seems simple and lightweight. (By the way, Plotly did not allow me to do what I wanted without touching the d3.js.). If this question is for some reason hard to solve in mpld3 (I don't see why it should be), please let me know how you would do it with a different package.

Comment: Can you share `pured3_output.html`

Comment: Yup: https://gist.github.com/tadamcz/c092ff7d191f7e3fbef5caf9b80e881a

Comment: It's better to generate it by running the Python though, because the ids are different on each run.

Comment: Thanks, will take a closer look tomorrow (heading to bed), do you want to do anything with the line other than drag it?

Comment: Thanks! :) I want to drag horizontally. Then on `d3.drag().on("end", ...)`, run some JS function to update a form field and submit the form. In the actual application there will be several vertical/horizontal lines that can be dragged independently.

Comment: Hey @AndrewReid, have you had a chance to look at this yet?

Comment: Not really, it has been a bit busier than expcted, only have had a few minutes here and there

Comment: Thanks, no problem!

Comment: I’ve seen you asking a similar line of questions on plot functionality/interactivity in the browser. Have you made progress here?